# Using localStorage to retrieve a stored array using JSON stringify

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using JavaScript to store an array in local Storage.  Reading this site gave me the idea of using JSON.stringify to convert the array to a string before storing it.  This code works to convert an array to a JSON string for local storage.

```
    localStorage["search_history_record"] = JSON.stringify(search_history_record);
```

My problem has been retrieving the array from local storage.  I can parse the array from the stored string in local storage (I checked this using console.log), but this parsed array will not save properly.

```
    search_history_record = JSON.parse(localStorage["search_history_record"]);
```

I've been unable to find a solution in other stack overflow questions to solve this problem so far.  Why would this console log the stored string back to an array properly, but not store the parsed string back to my local array?

Comment: Works fine with me. Please explain what specific is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by 'properly'? What's the error or what happens?

Comment: I can parse the string into an array.  But it is not storing into my browser's array for some reason.  For example, I can console log the local storage array.  I can see the array in local storage.  But when I check the value of the variable in my application, I still have an empty array.